# Removing side bar widgets from GovPress theme

Tags: widgets

[image]

I'm using the [GovPress theme](http://wordpress.org/themes/govpress), I've created a child theme. I now want to remove the sidebar widgets, as they are no use to me.

I've read multiple articles online, but none of them work. I believe I need to create a functions.php in my child theme, but what needs to go into this file?

Comment: Post your attempted solutions, please, even if they don't work. I assume you want to remove the widgets from the backend "Widget" control panel so that they are not taking up space?

Comment: Where can I find the govpress theme?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/themes/govpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are talking about the three default widgets that are included in the sidebar.php template. I would just simply copy the sidebar.php to the child theme, and then delete these widgets manually.

After deletion of these widgets, you will be left with only the following code in sidebar.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the main widget areas.
 *
 * @package GovPress
 */
?>
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
        <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'primary' ) ) : ?>

        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary -->
```

**EDIT 1**

For the sake of your content, you can do the following in your childtheme

```
    .content-area {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-width {
  max-width: 1160px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.site-main {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.full-width .site-main {
  margin: 0;
}

#secondary {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
}

.site-footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**

This is the only other code I could find to solve your problem. I have already modified it, so paste this in your style.css

```
.layout-sidebar-left .site-main {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.layout-sidebar-left #secondary {
  float: left;
}

.layout-sidebar-left .content-area {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```